# Prove an equation has no integer solutions...

Tags: diophantine-equations

I know that ${x^3} - 8{y^3} = 12$ has no integer solutions but how can I prove it? If I had to sit down with someone and convince them (at least, fairly) rigorously that it has no integer solutions. How would I do it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $ x $ must be even, and hence $ 8 $ divides $ 12 $...

Comment: I don't understand why x must be even or the implications of that.

Comment: 2 divides $8y^3+12$, so it must divide $x^3$. Hence $x$ must be even. Hence 8 divides $x^3$ and hence also $x^3-8y^3$, so 8 divides 12. Contradiction.

Comment: All even cubes are multiples of 8. Form the equation for $x^3$ and you will see it is even.

Comment: @almagest do you think this question must be down voted? I don't understand why.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN I didn't downvote it.

Comment: @the_hermit your comment should be added as an answer below so you get credit and so the question can be removed from unanswered queue.

Comment: Sure, added. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $ (x,y) $ is a solution. Then $ 2 | 8y^3 + 12 = x^3 $ implying $ 2 | x $. Writing $ x = 2k $ gives $ 8(k^3 - y^3) = 12 $, a contradiction as $ 8 $ doesn't divide $ 12 $.